# How to use passport to check user auth on certain route in Express

Tags: passport.js

All:

Im pretty new to Passport.js, right now, what I want is to check if a user is authenticated to access certain route, and I add passport auth on that route, but it seems like a deal loop:

What it suppost to behave is: when user hit that url, if not authed, redirect to /auth, otherwise just continue.

```
app.use("/url-must-be-auth", 
        passport.authenticate("local", {
            successRedirect: '/url-must-be-auth', 
            failureRedirect: '/auth'
        })
)

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {  
    debugger;
    done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(email, done) {  
    debugger;

    User.findOne({
        where: { email: email }
    })
    .then(function(user) {
    debugger;

        done(null, user);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
    debugger;

        done(err, null);
    });
});
```

The deserilize part never gets called.

Anyway, just forget what I have done, could anyone help with what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`passport.authenticate()` should be used just to login or signup routes

You can write middleware function that will check is user authenticated, otherwise redirect to login page

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
        next();
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

and pass it as a first function of a certain route:

```
app.get('/url-must-be-auth', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    //response
});
```